# CSS HTML How to make a larger image than div display in full in div

Tags: html, css

So I have a div with a background image; this div can grow in height and width depending on content/size of space for the div.

But regardless I would like the background image to be 100% in size displayed, this is because the background image has borders around it, and I need those displayed for a button-like effect.

```
div.leadgen {
  background: url(/Website6/Styles/leadgen_center.png) repeat-x;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

<div class="leadgen">
 <h3>
  This is the title
 </h3>        
 This is the description
</div>
```

EDIT

```
#solutionsNav div.leadgen {
background:url(/images/leadGen_bg2.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/leadGen_bg2.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/leadGen_bg2.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc);
padding: 10px;
color: #FFF;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

This works for me in all browsers ! The only thing I need to figure out is in IE 7 and 8 I don't want to use     background:url(/images/leadGen_bg2.png) no-repeat; because it seems to be doubling up.

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the CSS property [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) which is available since CSS3:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

See [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie) for IE support.

Comment: So there is no way to do it in IE7 and IE8 ? Because I would still need to support those

Comment: See if any of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895571/css-background-size-cover-in-internet-explorer-7) work for you.

Comment: Updated wit answer the only thing I need to figure out is not to use background url in ie7 and ie8

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only)

If you want this technique to work on a div instead of the body, add `position: relative;` to the div's css.