# How can I do "background-size: cover;" or "background-size: contain;" under IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css

I've a 200x200 px div in which I put a background-image.
The div is resizable and keep ratio.

In recent browsers, "background-size: cover;" or "background-size: contain;" works fine but under IE7, it doesn't work.

Does anybody have a suggestion / trick to fix that ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There was another thread a while back...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895571/css-background-size-cover-in-internet-explorer-7

Answer (score 0):

If the image is smaller than the div could you not repeat it using the following CSS?

```
{
background-image:url('bg.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

If not, could you please provide a link to the deployed code.

Comment: I found a solution in CSS. In fact, my background-image is just two red guidelines. Somebody suggests me to do that with CSS only without image. It's easier to code that and it's cross-browsers ! I should have thought of it !

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQThumb](https://github.com/pakcheong/jqthumb). It was built to fix background-size issue in IE6, IE7, and IE8